# Https отправка логина пароля

Tags: сервер, http, post, get, https

Необходимо передать на сервер логин и пароль, с http только начала разбираться.
И мне кажется все это не безопасным , если делать GET до я могу просто брутфорсом долбиться на сервер с логином и паролем пока тот не ответит , что логин и пароль правильный , c POST та же история приложение смогут разобрать на исходник и посмотреть что я отправляю и куда и так же брутфорсом. Или я в чем-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: Брутфорс не прокатит, если вы ограничите количество попыток со стороны сервера. Ну и в любом случае никакого GET

Comment: От перебора спасает только 2х-факторная авторизация и ограничения на сервере.

Comment: Передавать пароль в GET определенно нельзя, тк такие формы могут ломаться через зараженный сайт просто вставкой картинки 1х1 пиксель с подготовленным запросом в src и подобными атаками

Comment: Иногда реализуют chap, mschap авторизацию - тоесть не передают пароль в открытом виде. Но это для защиты от фишинга.

Comment: `я могу просто брутфорсом долбиться на сервер с логином и паролем пока тот не ответит` достаточно после неудачной аутентификации на секунду блокировать аутентификацию от данного логина и/или адреса-источника, и брутфорсить станет грустно...

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы)

Answer (score 0):

Передача пароля через Get является небезопасной, т.к. данные передаются в строке запроса, а эту строку логирует сам веб-сервер (тогда пароль окажется в текстовом файле в открытом виде) и все промежуточные Proxy, при настройках по умолчанию. Если ставить цель перехватывать пароли, то можно на proxy-серверах записывать и POST-запросы, по этому данные авторизации следует передавать только по HTTPS, благо есть let's encrypt и дешевые сертификаты.

Comment: То есть передача данных по HTTP никак не кореллирует с брутфорсом, от него нужно защищаться отдельно - ограничивая количество попыток за период времени на стороне сервера + можно добавить CAPTCHA после нескольких неправильных вводах пароля.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас практически все используют защищенное соединение, то есть HTTPS. Передача пароля по GET это не правильно. Как написали выше, от брутфорса спасет только двух этапная аутентификация ( Как пример: получение СМС кода, либо получение кода Google Auth / Либо отправка кода на почту ). Либо вы можете сделать ограниченное число попыток ввода логина пароля, далее делать блокировку IP адреса, с которого пытались войти, на какое то время.

Comment: Принудительные паузы на сервере - вполне разумный вариант. Но требуется исключить возможность DoS

Comment: Капча тоже второй фактор, если что.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём сначала и по порядку.

**Http**
`Http` - это протокол (Набор правил) для передачи информации. В чём разница между `HttpGet` и `HttpPost`? `HttpGet` - это запрос на получение информация, `HttpPost` - запрос для отправки информации на сервер. `HttpGet` имеет параметры для уточнения информации, какую нужно получить. `HttpPost` - имеет тело запроса, в котором передаётся информация

**Безопасность**
Передача логина и паролей это достаточно глубокая и очень сложная тема, в которой вам сейчас будет очень тяжело разобраться. Но давайте посмотрим основные моменты. Во-первых, **логин** и **пароль** должны передаваться `HttpPost` запросом.

Да, брут форс допустим, но для этого есть масса средств на стороне сервера. В конце концов, при развёртывании на сервер вы можете использовать утилиты на уровне ОС сервера которые фиксируют подозрительные и частые запросы и просто блокируют IP. Так же подобное можно сделать на уровне фреймворка если знаете, какие инструменты для этого использовать.